# Как исправить ошибку group function is nested too deeply в Oracle?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, select, group-by

Мне необходимо найти название товара (products.name) для каждой категории товаров (products_group.name), которое чаще всего упоминается в таблице покупок SaleMap. Вот так выглядят схемы данных таблиц:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот код:

```
SELECT pg.name, p.name FROM product_group pg, products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp
WHERE pg.pg_id = p.pg_id and 
      p.prod_id = pl.prod_id and 
      pl.dat = sp.dat and 
      p.prod_id = (SELECT p1.prod_id FROM products p1, pricelist pl1, salemap sp1 
                                     WHERE p.prod_id = p1.prod_id and 
                                           pl.dat = pl1.dat and
                                           sp.dat = sp1.dat 
                                     HAVING max(count(p1.prod_id))
                                     GROUP BY p1.prod_id)
```

Здесь я для того, чтобы найти товар из каждой группы, который упоминают максимальное количество раз в таблице покупок salemap, прибегаю к такой конструкции из агрегатных функций:

```
HAVING max(count(p1.prod_id))
```

На что я получаю ошибку:

```
ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply
```

Пробовал также реализовать данный запрос с помощью такой конструкции:

```
HAVING count(p1.prod_id) = max(count(p1.prod_id))
```

Однако получал такую же ошибку. Подскажите, как всё-таки реализовать запрос для получения название товара (products.name) для каждой категории товаров (products_group.name), которое чаще всего упоминается в таблице покупок SaleMap без ошибок.

Comment: Похожая задача: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226411/ora-00935-error-group-nested-too-deeply. Должно помочь.

Comment: MAX(COUNT()) - это два уровня группировки, что недопустимо. Легко решается заменой внешнего получения максимума групповой функцией на сортировку по убыванию со взятием первого значения.

Answer (score 0):

```
HAVING count(p1.prod_id) = ( SELECT max(count(p1.prod_id)) FROM p1 );
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Перд тем, как дать ответ, проверяйте решние [на работоспособность](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ad9480e898c286d93bb4d1523c61b61). Ваше решение даст ошибку: ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY.